# Invoke EntryPoint of assembly without showing any window - VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, exe, .net-assembly, invoke, entry-point

I need to execute an application embeeded in my resources . Heres my code :

```
Dim MainAssembly As Reflection.Assembly = Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
Dim resourceStream As Stream = MainAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream("MyApp.Nircmd.exe")

If resourceStream Is Nothing Then
       Throw New NullReferenceException("error")
End If

Dim toolAssemblyBuffer(CInt(resourceStream.Length) - 1) As Byte
resourceStream.Read(toolAssemblyBuffer, 0, toolAssemblyBuffer.Length)
resourceStream.Close()

AudioTool = Reflection.Assembly.Load(toolAssemblyBuffer)


 Dim args() As String = {Application.StartupPath, "argumentsHere"}
 Dim parameters = New Object() {args}
 Try
 AudioTool.EntryPoint.Invoke(Nothing, parameters)
                  
 Catch
 End Try
```

This application opens a new cmd.exe window everytime , so , **i need to invoke the EntryPoint without showing any window .**
Is there a WindowStyle property or something equal in an assembly ?
Thanks

Comment: It's hard to reproduce the problem. Please share a step by step [MCVE].

Comment: @RezaAghaei The problem is that i want to run the assembly without allow it to display any window . I Can't say it more easily

Comment: I think your issue is that this is a console application.  You'll need a different application type.  I'm not completely certain, though, whether any of the windowed application types will work the way you want.  A quick check on a WPF application shows that I still need to provide a startup form for it (no option to use a `Sub Main` instead).